# Android match uri matcher returns -1

Tags: android, android-sqlite, uri, android-contentprovider

I want to make query on the already made database where case 1 is to get all data while case 2 is to bring me two values where user_id and dt (time stamp with format "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss") match via, Content Provider. However when I do a query with code 2 on Content Provider, the method match of uri matcher returns -1 while if I do with code 1, works fine. Also I tried using default instead of case 2 in switch and it works fine too. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on what might the cause be.

Edit 1: I have tried removing the "/" from method addUri().

Edit 2: I have added the getType() method.

Content Provider Class

```
    private static UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.foo";
    public static final String CONTENT_URI = "content://"+AUTHORITY;

    static {
     uriMatcher = new UriMatcher (UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
     uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "/data",1);
     uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "/data/#",2);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DbHelper (getContext ());
        return false;
    }
.
.
.
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        Cursor result = null;
        int bar = uriMatcher.match (uri);
        switch (bar){
            case 1:
                result = dbHelper.selectAll ();
                break;
            default:
                String[] data = uri.getPathSegments ().toArray (new String[0]);
                result = dbHelper.selectDataByUserId (data[1],data[2]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

MainActivity Class

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.

        ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver ();
        String[] test = (String[]) Uri.parse (DataContentProvider.CONTENT_URI+"/data/"+user_id+"/"+dt).getPathSegments ().toArray (new String[0]);
        Cursor cursor  = resolver.query (Uri.parse (DataContentProvider.CONTENT_URI+"/data/"+user_id+"/"+dt),null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst ()) {
            lon.setText (cursor.getString (1));
            lat.setText (cursor.getString (2));
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.exercise">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.foo">
        <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.foo"
            android:name=".DataContentProvider"
            android:exported="true">
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading forward slash `/` from the added URIs to the matcher.

So replace:

```
 uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "/data",1);
 uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "/data/#",2);
```

with:

```
 uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "data",1);
 uriMatcher.addURI (AUTHORITY, "data/#",2);
```

Comment: Nothing has I changed.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. Can you check the AUTHORITY value as well

Comment: @Azzarian can you tell if you override `getType` method of the `ContentProvider`? if so please share it

Comment: I have added the getType() method. Also I have checked that the AUTHORITY value is correct if you mean that.

Comment: @Azzarian can you share the mainfest file ?